# Using Odoo 15, is it possible to reserve at the stock.move.line level

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I am trying to reserve a product for stock.picking record.

I want to reserve at the line level due to the picking workflow. I have tried to remove all other lines, and then just reserve the stock.picking but this still attempts to reserve the entire order. I need it at the line level due to the fact multiple fractional amount might be picked.

Is it even possible to reserve at the stock.move.line level ?

So I create the line as such. Which works.

```
# Update the move line associated with the move record
    move_line = odoo.env['stock.move.line'].create({
        'move_id': move.id,
        'product_id': product_id,
        'qty_done': amount_picking,
        'location_id': quant_location_id,  # Use the location of the quant_id
        ##change to source location
        'location_dest_id': move.location_id.id,
        'lot_id': lot_id or False,
        'product_uom_id': move.product_uom.id,  # Add the missing 'product_uom_id' field
        'picking_id': picking_id,
    })
```

What I want to achieve is having ONLY this line be reserved.

Comment: not very clear what you are trying to do, could you share more details? and what you expect?

Comment: and the picking have more lines?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new `stock.picking` with a new `stock.move` with only that line in order to make it work as expected. The Picking will act over all the move lines